# How to correctly benchmark sequential read speeds on 2.5" hard drive with fio on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, truenas, benchmark, fio

Like suggested in https://askubuntu.com/a/991311 I tested the read speed of a 2.5" spinning hard drive on a TrueNAS/FreeBSD system.

For "Sequential READ speed with big blocks":

```
fio --name TEST --eta-newline=5s --filename=fio-tempfile.dat --rw=read --size=500m --io_size=10g --blocksize=1024k --ioengine=posixaio --fsync=10000 --iodepth=32 --direct=1 --numjobs=1 --runtime=60 --group_reporting
```

I got 8037 MB/s.

I don’t believe this.

I did replace `liaio` with `posixaio`, do I need another engine?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are testing the speed of your system's filesystem cache because you are only `fsync`ing every 10000 I/Os (so that's every 9GBytes). Does your speed change if you use you choose use the [`direct=1`](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-direct) option?